# trigonometric inequality: $(y-x)(\cos{x}+\cos{y})\leq 2\sin(y-x)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I have trouble proving the following inequality, which I have confirmed is true using wolfram:
$$(y-x)(\cos{x}+\cos{y})\leq 2\sin(y-x)$$
with $0\leq x<y \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

I have tried expanding the RHS using the formula for $\sin(y-x)$ and rearranging the terms but to no good results.

I would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0 < d \le \pi/2$ we have
$$
\sin(d) = \int_0^d \cos(t)\, dt > d \, \frac{1+\cos(d)}{2}
$$
because $\cos$ is *concave* on that interval. Applying this to $d=y-x$ gives
$$
 \frac{\sin(y-x)}{y-x} > \frac{1+\cos(y-x)}2 \ge \frac{\cos(x) + \cos(y)}2
$$
because $\cos$ is decreasing on $[0, \pi/2]$.

Answer (score 0):

Using $\cos x+\cos y=2\cos \frac{y-x}{2}\cos \frac{y+x}{2}$ and $\sin (y-x)=2\sin \frac{y-x}{2}\cos \frac{y-x}{2}$, it is equivalent with:

$$(y-x)\cos \frac{y-x}{2}\cos \frac{y+x}{2}\leq 2\sin \frac{y-x}{2}\cos \frac{y-x}{2}$$

$\frac{y-x}{2}\in (0,\frac{\pi}{4})$ where $\cos$ is positive, so it is enough to prove:

$$(y-x)\cos \frac{y+x}{2}\leq 2\sin \frac{y-x}{2}$$

or

$$t\cos(t+x)\leq \sin t$$

where $t=\frac{x-y}{2}$. Now $0<t \leq t+x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $\cos$ is decreasing over $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, so:

$$t\cos(t+x)\leq t\cos t\leq \tan t \cos t =\sin t$$

I used $\tan t \geq t$ for $t\geq 0$ which is known.